# Independent div toggling

Tags: jquery, html, css, notifications, scroll

I'm making a navigation bar like Twitter, but I want that one div inside that bar scrolls down with notifications or news, and the other bar content stay "as is". Any suggestion?
http://jsfiddle.net/fdezluis96/JJ29E/

```
#navigation{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
padding:5px;
color: #fff;
height:32px;
font-size:20px;
background: #333;
}​
```

And this is the main HTML code

```
<div id="navigation">This is the main div static content
    <div id="subnavigation">This is the scrolling content.</div>
</div>​
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the live-pin.com website, this seems to work:

```
<!-->Add "position: relative;" to have a non-statically position parent.</-->
<div class="nav-collapse" style="position:  relative;">
```

and

```
<!-->Change inline styles from "background:#fff; width:300px; overflow:auto;" to "background: #fff; border: 1px solid #fff; border-top-width:0px; border-bottom-width:0px; background: #666; border-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 0px; position: absolute; max-width: 300px;" (mostly from the fiddle, but "position: absolute" to keep it where it is and remove it from the normal document flow; removing it from the document flow is what allows it to escape its parent's containment.) </-->
<li id="notificationss" style="background: #fff; border: 1px solid #fff; border-top-width:0px; border-bottom-width:0px; background: #666; border-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 0px; position: absolute; max-width: 300px;">
    dssdadsadas
    <br>dsadsasdadssdadsadas
    <br>dsadsasdadssdadsadas
    <br>dsadsasdadssdadsadas
    <br>dsadsasdadssdadsadas
    <br>dsadsasdadssdadsadas
    <br>dsadsasda
</li>
```

Comment: Seems to work for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/JJ29E/6/ Unless I'm misunderstanding what you want...

Comment: not exactly what I mean, I have 2 sections A B C, where C = A, both will be CSS-Same, and B is the scroll content. I want A to have a defined height (24px) and it keeps like that, static, since C is the same as A, it would be static too, and B has content that would be "flying" in the page, like in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fdezluis96/JJ29E/, the tables example.

Comment: then, this is exactly what I meant, but doesn't work on my pages, http://live-pin.com/ theres the example D: help please